# Google Docs Add-on cannot get published to G-Suite Marketplace after OAuth credentials were approved

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have just spend a great amount of time going back and forth with Google regarding this issue and still cannot figure anything out. I have built an add-on for Google Docs, which is merely a copy of the add-on that I previously build for Google Sheets in 2014. Google OAuth team approved all of the scopes that this add-on uses, but now when I try to publish this add-on to G-Suite marketplace, the Publish button is not activated even after I enter all of the required fields and screenshots. I am currently also awaiting for Chrome Web Store listing approval, but I do not think that the two are connected with one another? Can anyone please suggest anything, I am totally lost. My previous add-on did get published without any complication in G-Suite marketplace and Chrome Web Store but for some reason, this new add-on did not.

Google recommended to ask this question here, so am merely following their advice.

Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

The Chrome Webstore listing is approved, but there is still an issue with G-Suite Marketplace.

Comment: Hi, do you see a button 'Why i can not publish'? it may provide more info. for my case it was because of a wrong field in the manifest file.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm in a similar boat (2014 Docs Add-on that I'm expanding to Slides). Did you create a *Standard GCP project* and move the two add-ons to point to it? The **G Suite Marketplace SDK > Configuration** looks OK, but the **G Suite Marketplace SDK > Publish** is not auto-populating, like the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-overview?hl=en_US#publishing_to_both_the_chrome_web_store_and_the_g_suite_marketplace) says it should. How did you contact Google?

Comment: Yep, I'm in the same boat with a Sheets add-on that I'd published to the Chrome Web Store in 2017, but disappeared from all the sheets it used to be in and now is nowhere to be found in the G Suite Marketplace, and the Publish button is constantly disabled.

Comment: I did manage to resolve it. I have had to contact the doc advisor and they have helped me to do this. I do not think that you can do it on your own as some access will be limited and there is only a limitted amount of things that you can do without the involvement of the docs advisor.

Comment: @AlexB - who or what is the "docs advisor" and how does one get in contact with them?

Comment: I just got some help in an Issue Tracker entry (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136107423) that told me to contact cws-migration-support@google.com, so we'll see if that helps get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Update: I got help from that email (cws-migration-support@google.com) and my add-on is now live on the G Suite Marketplace!  (In my case, I had had to reauthorize my OAuth certification, but that apparently didn't propagate to the G Suite Marketplace approval, so it had to be done manually by a Google admin.)